# creating server side for android app that makes a request every few seconds

Tags: android, web-services, server

I am creating an android app where one user will be able to see another user on the map.

Here's the thing
There's a web service, the client request all the logged-in users from the web service then renders the users as a marker on the map. After every few seconds it makes a request again.
I've got the client side figured out and working.

The problem lies on the server side.
The way i am doing it is:

- The web service receives the client request and saves the client lat-lng in the database
- Retrieves the other active users from the database and send them back to client.

It works. But I know it's not the way to do it.

Here's the problem areas:

- client calls the web service every 5 seconds, so the web service has to update the client location in the DB every seconds.(*BAD*)
- If there are 100 users then the web service would have to make 100 updates every 5 seconds.(*VERY BAD*)

How can I improve the server logic?

Comment: 100 updates in 5 seconds isn't bad at all but your current design won't scale well. You'd be better off only storing values in the database every now and then and working entirely in memory for the rest of the time.

Comment: Exactly I know it wouldn't scale well. I did thought of working entirely in memory and at regular intervals, update all the users lat-lng in DB. However, I have no idea how to do that. Would I have to create a separate server side application and keep it running?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new Thread so that the call don't lock up the device if the call takes longer than expected. The AsyncTask is an easy way to use multithreading, but it lacks the functionality of repeating tasks. I would say that you are best of either using a `Timer` or the newer `ScheduledExecutorService`. If you chose to use the Timer you create a TimerTask that you can hand it. The ScheduledExecutorService takes a Runnable instead.

You might want to wrap the thread in a Service (The Service does not provide a new Thread), but this is not always necessary depending on your needs.

As suggested , you can also use the Handler.postDelayed(). Although you still need to create a new thread and then call Looper.prepare() on it:

class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

```
  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }
```

}
(Code from Looper docs)

Also; calls to a webservice every 5 second seems way too frequent, especially if the user is on a slow connection or there are data that needs to be transferred, try to reduce the calls as much as possible.

Comment: Its kind of like a tracking app, where one user sees the other, i want it to be as accurate as possible. But even if I decrease the call to webservice, the problem is still the same that the server design is not good enough. It wont be able to handle a lot of users simultaneously.

Comment: what is your server configuration?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Basically I have written a web service in C# and I am using MS-SQL to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

use Google Cloud Messaging service. Requesting every 5 second is a bad idea, and will drain battery too.. Only changes needs to be updated from server to client. So Push notification is the right way.

In your example - Not all the 100 users location will be changing every 5 seconds. Also normalize the change -(say few change in few meters can be ignored - no need to notify client)

In case you are going by polling mechanism, server can sent all the location update with one rest API.

Comment: I have tried using GCM. The problem with it is after 5 minutes of inactivity, it doesn't deliver the message instantly but delays for 10 mins or longer. Plus I need to send the other-users[] back to the client which (I am not sure) could be more than 4kb, depending on the number of active users. I don't need to request the server all the time, only when the activity is resumed, so I could pause the request-sending when the user leaves the activity.

Comment: sending back to server is only for the user for the specific device right?

Do sending back data only where there is sufficient change in location (may be more than few meters)

Comment: Alryt, I think what you are saying is when one user changes its location then send its position to the server, the server then broadcast that user position to all the other-users. That would means the server would need to push the message to the client and hence no client request. GCM seems very unreliable but it does sound like a good design. Thanks, I'm gonna see if it works.

Comment: i am applying your scenario here. If 100 users are changing location at the same time,then 100 will send the request t the server.Then server will broadcast 100x100 times.It means by this design also your called problem is not satisfied.You should not think of server capabilities at this much load